# React router - render() doesn't fire when just the query parameter changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I have a container component that takes a `?"type=specificType"`  parameter.  When that parameter changes via a Link, i want to re-render with different subset of the data.

How would you suggest that I handle this?
Example:
Links on the page -  ALL  |  FISH  |  BIRDS  |  MAMMALS

The route is `http://baseURL/animals`  and will render all animals.

When this link is selected `<Link to="/animals?type=birds" />`  I want to rerender the page with JUST the subset of animals that are BIRDS, but nothing triggers with this change.

Any suggestion on how to make this happen?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't believe I didn't think of this before, but the answer was very simple. I passed a handler down to the component with the filter links.  When any given link was selected the "update" method simply adjusted the data and called the render() method from there.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you please provide details with example code? I am facing the same problem at the moment.

Comment: What *handler*? what `update` method?? what are you talking about? can you make it clearer how was this solved? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `Link` you can put a `Button` and in the `onClick` handler you can call `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.setState(this.state)` to trigger a re-render, and then redirect manually using `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

You could always listen to route changes by using:

> browserHistory.listen()

Basically I placed it in a variable 'routeListener' and call it on 'componentWillMount()'. And run whatever method 'handleRouteChange()' I wanted to call.

And make sure to stop the listener by calling routeListener() in 'componentWillUnMount()'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

let routeListener = null;

export default class SomeComponent extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        routeListener = browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
            this.handleRouteChange();
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        routeListener();
    }

    handleRouteChange() {
        console.log("Detect change in route");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Hello World
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

I hope this would fix your problem. Good luck